# Replacing string values in cell array with numbers

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have a cell array which contains some descriptions, namely `my_des`.

```
 my_des = [{'FRD'} {'1'}; {'UNFRD'} {'2'}; {'OTH'} {'3'};];
```

I also have an approximately 5000x1 cell array. The elements in this array are either `'FRD'`, `'UNFRD'` or `'OTH'`.

What I want to do is replace these text values with the corresponding numeric values in `my_des`.

Currently my only idea (which I think isn't that great) is to loop through `my_des` and do a string replacement.

---

**Example**:

So say my current vector looks like this:

```
FRD
FRD
OTH
UNFRD
OTH
FRD
```

Then my desired output would be this:

```
1
1
3
2
3
1
```

The numbers come from the `my_des` array

Comment: do these values `'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'` not exist in your original array? If those values are coming from `my_des`, why dont you simply select the second column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to use the *characters* `'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'` or just the *numbers* `1`, `2`, `3`? The distinction is the difference between a 1 line answer and a 2 line answer!

Based on your example, let's use the following data:

```
arr = {'FRD'; 'FRD'; 'OTH'; 'UNFRD'; 'OTH'; 'FRD'};
```

Get the row index within `my_des` of each element in `arr`, and use that to get the corresponding 2nd column values...

```
% If you just want the *number* then this is all you need
[~, idx] = ismember(arr, my_des);
% idx is the row within column 1 of my_des where the value in arr is found
% >> idx = [1; 1; 3; 2; 3; 1]

% If you want to get the values my_des then use idx as a row index
out = mydes(idx, 2);
% out is the corresponding values from the 2nd column of my_des, whatever they may be.
% >> out = {'1'; '1'; '3'; '2'; '3'; '1'};
```

---

Aside: why are you declaring a cell array by concatenating 1-element cell arrays for `my_des`? Instead, you can just do this:

```
my_des = {'FRD',   '1'; 
          'UNFRD', '2'; 
          'OTH',   '3'};
```